# Retrieve row number if row is identical to specified vector

Tags: r, matrix

Consider the following matrix:

```
MAT <- matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3,1:9)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I want to retrieve the row number if I provide a vector which exactly matches a row in `MAT`. So if I provide `c(2,5,8)`, I should get back 2. I'm unsure how to accomplish this; the closest thing I know is using `which` to find the location of a single number in a matrix. An alternate could be a very slow quadruple `for` loop checking if the given vector matches a row in the matrix. Is there a one line solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `identical` to test, `apply` loop and `which` to identify:

```
which(apply(MAT,1,function(x) identical(x,c(2L,5L,8L))))
[1] 2
```

Note that the values in the matrix are stored as integers, so you need to specify that in the vector to test.

Comment: Note that if you're **not** dealing with integers but rather with floats, you may be better off using `all.equal` or `cgwtools::approxeq` to avoid machine precision problems.

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply` a simple matching function to each row, then use `which` to find the row number:

```
search_vec = c(2, 5, 8)

vec_matches = apply(MAT, 1, function(row, search_vec) all(row == search_vec), search_vec)
row_num = which(vec_matches)
```